# How to access values of a concrete interface implementation, when using the interface as a generic parameter to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to implement some generic models for a project, where I need each model to hold a value type of ICountryInformation. This interface will have different values depending on which country is implemented.

However, what I struggle with is how to actually use this in the right way. For instance, given a method:

```
DoSomething(ICountryInformation info) 
{
}
```

Say I have parsed a concrete implementation of ICountryInformation called `GermanyInformation` then I want to be able to fetch the information in relation to that concrete instance of ICountryInformation within my `DoSomething()` method.

But I can't seem to figure out how I can work around the fact that ICountryInformation do not have the concrete values of the GermanyInformation class which implements it.

How can I access the values of GermanyInformation, when it is parsed as an ICountryInformation beside actually having to cast it to a value inside the method? Is it even possible?

Comment: As you know an interface is a contract that exposes methods (and public properties), but if you need to cast it to a concrete object, then your design and/or the interface is flawed. Please tell us more about the project so that we can help you.

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually want to achieve... And using county information as an example of interface implementation (which is probably not your real scenario) does not make things more clear either. Normally one would expect information about particular country/entity to be *instance* of some class rather than derived class and simply expose information via properties of that class (or corresponding interface). As @MarcoLuzzara said providing real goal may help with getting an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am thinking the following: How can I access the values of GermanyInformation, when it is parsed as an ICountryInformation beside actually having to cast it to a value inside the method? - is a pretty good idea of what I want to achieve. I cannot see how that is unclear in any way. 
The answer could be "not possible" or it could be something else.

Comment: Since you've accepted answer that *does not* show how "access the values of GermanyInformation" it is even more confusing... The issue is not that what you described is unclear - but rather what you described is generally considered wrong thing to do... and example you picked to demonstrate the problem is not helping. So providing good answer that follows common practices and helps you too requires understanding of your *actual* goal (so far it looks like you picked some strange route to achieve that  - see [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the task of `DoSomething` to get the information. You must pass it as parameter when calling it

```
DoSomeThing(new GermanyInformation());
```

It makes sense to implement this information as singleton.

```
public class GermanyInformation : ICountryInformation
{
    public static readonly GermanyInformation Instance = new GermanyInformation();

    // Hide the constructor
    private GermanyInformation()
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

Then call it with

```
DoSomeThing(GermanyInformation.Instance);
```

If you want `DoSomeThing` to always use the German information, remove the parameter

```cs
DoSomething() 
{
    ICountryInformation info = GermanyInformation.Instance;
}
```

---

Another approach is to use a generic method or a method using a type parameter of an enclosing generic class (without the singleton implementation here)

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : ICountryInformation, new()
{
    ICountryInformation info = new T();
}
```

call it with

```
DoSomething<GermanyInformation>();
```

or with a generic class

```
public class CountryService<T> where T : ICountryInformation, new()
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        ICountryInformation info = new T();
    }
}
```

call it with

```
var service = new CountryService<GermanyInformation>();
service.DoSomething();
```

---

Note that you can't cast `ICountryInformation` to the desired country information. It references an object of a specific country information and you can't change that to another country.

The interface itself isn't an object. It is a contract a class can implement. You can then access the members of it in a neutral way through the interface, without having to know to which country it relates.

Comment: Thanks, this could work for me in my use case that I currently have. I was not sure how to make this in a smart way!